# Google feed api in a nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, google-feed-api

I have a php application that uses the google feed api to get the feeds I want and display them. I was wondering how can I call the google feed api from a nodejs application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use node's `http.request()` (or the shortcut version `http.get()`) functionality; that's conceptually the same thing you must be currently doing in PHP.

You might find that installing and using Mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/) module would make things even simpler.